# Longest Increasing Subsequences

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, bitmask

For a digit N we define **LIS Array** as

Longest strictly increasing subsequence of digits ending with that digit.

For example, let us say 4-digit number is 1531, then the **LIS array would be [1, 2, 2, 1].**
 The length of longest increasing subsequence ending at first digit is 1 (the digit 1 itself) and at the second digit is 2 ([1, 5]), at third digit is also 2 ([1, 3]), and at the 4th digit is 1 (the digit 1 itself).

[Problem Statement](https://www.codechef.com/problems/DIGITLIS)

Here i am using bitmasking algorithm

```
for(int i=2;i<=n;i++){
    int x = Lis[i];

    if(x==1){
        for(int j=1;j<(1<<10);j++){
            int last=-1;
            int len=0;
            for(int k=9;k>=0;k--)
                if((j&(1<<k))!=0){ 
                    len++;
                    if(len==1)
                        last=k;
                }

            for(int k=0;k<=last;k++){
                dp[1<<k][i] = (dp[1<<k][i]+ dp[j][i-1])%mod;
            }
        }

        continue;
    }

    for(int j=1;j<(1<<10);j++){
        int last=-1;
        int len=0;
        for(int k=9;k>=0;k--)
            if((j&(1<<k))!=0){ 
                len++;
                if(len==1)
                    last=k;
            }
        if(len+1!=x) continue;

        for(int k=last+1;k<10;k++)
            dp[j|(1<<k)][i] = (dp[j|(1<<k)][i]+ dp[j][i-1])%mod; 
    }
}
```

But it's not working correctly ? Can anyone explain me correct approach to deal with this ?

Comment: well, technically speaking this isn't a subsequence, as sequences are defined as **consecutive** integers. And debugging some deeply nested code with ambiguous variable-names and no documentation is definitely nothing anyone will do for you. Please either refactor your code, or add a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

For each digit store the length of the longest associated sequence and go through the sequence:

```
max_len[]
result

for digit in sequence
    max_len[digit] = max(sub_array(max_len, 1, digit - 1)) + 1
    result.append(max_len[digit])
```

since `max_len` has length 9 or 10, depending upon whether 0 is allowed in the input-sequence, this solution runs in `O(n)`. `result` contains the LIS-array.

The basic idea is to define the LIS of an element `e` in the input-sequence recursively as the LIS of any element that precedes `e` and is smaller than `e`. Since we want the longest sequence we obviously choose the predecessor with the longest sequence. We can memorize this value as the longest sequence that ends with element `e` for later use and add the length of the LIS of `e` to the output sequence.